# why JSONDecoder gives typeMismatch for valid json

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I am using JSONDecoder to convert JSON into Objects.

Here is the code. It usually works fine.

```
         do{
                print("Hi")
                       if Data != nil{
                        let model =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Base.self, from: Data!)
                       }
            }
            catch{
                print("Error:\(error)")
            }
```

But I am getting below Error

> Error:typeMismatch(Swift.Double,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "rod", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "nod", intValue: nil),
>   _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "meta", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "label", intValue:
>   nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a
>   string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

It used to work fine. Any help in resolving this would be appreciated

Comment: Please **read** the error message carefully. It's pretty clear. The value for key `label` in the dictionary `meta` in the first item of the array `nod` in the dictionary `rod` is a `String` rather than expected `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be a data type issue.

You have to investigate the **Decodable protocol** in **JSONDecoder().decode** which is in your case

```
Base.self
```

Basically one of the meta class/struct member is **Double** while it's supposed to be **String**.

I'm not doing any advertisement but personally I find https://app.quicktype.io/ easy to use and it's mostly error free when it comes to generating Decodable protocol for any JSON.

I usually copy paste my JSON in QuickType and it'll generate me the Structs to hold my JSON value and I copy paste these Structs to my code